Nav-link anchor tag click event is not working properly
enter image description here
I used anchor tag for navigating the content from one webpart to another webpart. In anchor tag click event use the smooth scrollIntoView. But it is not working properly in one of the navigation click event.
could someone explain why? for one particular link is not navigating from one link to another webpart
